# Why our website is not reachable from our office (static IP) but works fine on other ISP?

Tags: networking, router, traceroute, blacklist

From our office, we can't reach our website anymore.

But from home (or other ISP network, ever from cellphone), it is reachable! 
I performed a traceroute from office and the data stop at `116.251.117.165` IP address.

[image: tracert info]

The same traceroute from home runs fine and reach the endpoint (so the website is working from home).

So, what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Which website is it? IP `116.251.117.165` seems to be in `alibaba-inc.com`, so if you are on a large network with lots of firewalls, you should consult the administrator(s).

Comment: Where is your website hosted? Do you host it yourself on a server machine in your own office, or is it hosted at a professional hosting service / data center? If it's in your own office, it could be that you have an office NAT gateway router tha doesn't support NAT loopback.

Comment: our website is hosted on an alibaba cloud plateform (like amazon cloud but alibaba one)

Comment: our ISP changed our ip address, so now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask your browser to display a URL, your browser needs to know which IP address is linked to the website name. Your browser requests the IP address of the website name by asking DNS servers. The DNS server responds with,... this website lives at this IP address. Changing your DNS provider to (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) could help. That’s the DNS server provided by google.  Also try requesting the IP address directly into your web browser.

Comment: i tried to ping and tracerroute the website ip address instead the domain and the result is the same. i guess the problem does not come from the DNS but from the distant 116.251.117.165  node (which is not our server but another node to get there)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to try and troubleshoot:

1. Change your DNS settings to 8.8.8.8 (Google).
2. Use IMCP ping to see if you can get a response from the server.
3. Are you behind a proxy in the office? Check proxy/ firewall / ACL settings